# Javascript game with socket.io. Server lagging

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

Hello I'm learning javascript by making game with socket.io and node.js. I would ask you about how it should work. Now all positions of players, player's bullets and other stuff are stored on server and server emit this to client. Client when get data draw everything on screen. Is that everything okay ? When I deploy server.js file on free node.js server I get lags but when I run it on my PC I didnt get it. Is this server fault ?

I can paste link to repository if it will help and thanks for help.

Comment: It's hard to to say for certain without checking specifically, but a free remote server may not have adequate resources (e.g. processing power or connection speed) required, especially compared to a local server. In addition, the distance from the remote server and the connection speed of the client might also hinder performance. Gaming requires very low latency between client and server. Try pinging the server from the client you are testing with and see how much is the lag.

Comment: Okay so when I put server.js file on better server lags should dissapear ?
And can u check my server mechanics ?
https://github.com/kacper1230/kyl.io/blob/Save/server.js
Is the checkBullets function correct ?

Comment: It might, but it depends on many factors, including the geographical location of the server compared to the client and the connection quality on both ends. I suggest you check this with the existing server, so you will know in advance what are the current bottle necks.

Comment: About the repository you linked, Stack Overflow is not meant for debugging your code. If you have a specific question about this code, you should post it separately. You can also check the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the server you deploy to permits websocket connections. socket.io will switch to long polling via http if it's not able to use websocket. This may cause the the lags you experience.

You may also check this in the browser web console by inspecting the network traffic and see if packets are sent over the websocket or http.

Answer (score 1):

I look into your code in repository and it's kinda naive. My main suggestions:

1) ***Don't send updated data to often.*** You are trying send client data every 33ms, but it's kinda heavy even for native games. Send data every second, for sync world state, and extrapolate it on client (just visually part, not internal logic... e.g. emulate bullets fly and collisions, but not destroying objects, it's servers jobs).

2) ***Send only new data.*** Try to send only diffs. It's very tricky and hard, but worth of work. You may combine it with p. 1 and, for example, every 5 seconds send internal state and every 0.5 sec send diff with previously state.

3) ***Send only events.*** If bullet fly 50 frames straightforward than their is no need to send 50 positions. Just send "Bullet #uniqid start flying from XY with speed +1, 0" and than send "Bullet #uniqid blowup at X, Y and destroyed objects [list of id's]"

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand my suggestions.